# Use Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension method in C# to get the file name but the display is not complete

Tags: c#, file-manipulation

This is the simple C# code I wrote :

```
string file = @"D:\test(2021/02/10).docx";
            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```

I thought I would get the string "test(2021/02/10)" , but I got this result "10)".
How can I solve such a problem?

Comment: Why use `AsSpan`? Why the `foreach`?

Comment: The slash character is interpreted as a directory path.  The character is probably not allowed in file names of the system you are using anyway.

Comment: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` doesn't return an array.

Comment: In terms of *solving* the problem: use a dash instead: `d:\test(2021-02-10).docx`. That follows ISO-8601 formatting, as a nice side-effect.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong code, causing trouble to you, and I have corrected it .

Comment: But Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension can indeed return an array now. The returned data type is ReadOnlySpan<char>

Comment: @ Jon Skeet good idea. Thanks

Comment: ReadOnlySpan<char> != array, Naming your variable `fileNameArr` is misleading. And iterating over it with `foreach` will give you a single character at a time, which seems unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: OK, my fault . this is a test program, so I am not very rigorous in naming it.Thanks for correcting. Llama

Comment: Typo: `/` is not allowed on a Windows system and in fact disrupts the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wonder why would you want such behavior. On windows slashes are treated as separator between directory and subdirectory (or file).

So, basically you are not able to create such file name.

And since slashes are treated as described, it is very natural that method implementation just checks what's after last slash and extracts just filename.

If you are interested on how the method is implemented take a look at [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,e36b3edc1f3e2c8d)

Comment: You *can* create that as a filename, it's just that it represents a directory under D: called `test(2021`, with a directory under that called `02`, with a file under that called `10).docx`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hm you are correct (never even think of it that way to be honest :P ) - but I am trying to give "high level" of understanding :) without going into much details :)